# CMake No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5

I have a problem building my Qt5 project via cmake.

I run the command `cmake .. && make`  from the directory `build` and I receive the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lengine-lib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/blacklist-engine-cli.dir/build.make:102: src/blacklist-engine-cli] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:117: src/CMakeFiles/blacklist-engine-cli.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I have searched this topic briefly, however when I ran this project without Qt5Sql, using only Qt5Core I have no problem at all building the project. In order to build the project without Qt5Sql I just have to remove the `db` folder, and delete lines referring to that in my other CMakeLists.txt files. My question is:

**Why does it work if I want to include only Qt5Core, and why does it not work when I also include Qt5Sql? What am I doing wrong including Qt5Sql?**

Please do not include answers related to QtCreator, or Qt installation errors. I have checked my Qt installation folder, and I have Qt5Core and Qt5Sql on the same directory level installed.

I am using *Ubuntu 20.04*, *cmake version 3.16.3*, *Qt version 5.12.8*

`ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake`

> Qt5            Qt5Core  Qt5Gui      Qt5OpenGL            Qt5PrintSupport  Qt5Test     Qt5Xml
> Qt5Concurrent  Qt5DBus  Qt5Network  Qt5OpenGLExtensions  Qt5Sql           Qt5Widgets

I have the following structure in my project:

```
root
├── CMakeModules
│   └── Qt.cmake
├── build
├── src
│   ├── db
│   │    ├── dbmanager.cpp
│   │    ├── dbmanager.h
│   │    └── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── engine
│   │    ├── scanner.cpp
│   │    ├── scanner.h
│   │    └── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cpp
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(blacklist-engine)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeModules)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

**CMakeModules/Qt.cmake**:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Sql)
```

**src/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
include(Qt)

add_subdirectory(
    db   
    engine
)

add_executable(blacklist-engine-cli main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
    blacklist-engine-cli
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Sql
    engine-lib
    db-lib
)
```

**src/main.cpp**:

```
#include <QtCore>

#include "db/dbmanager.h"
#include "engine/scanner.h"
...
```

**src/db/CMakeLists.txt (updated)**:

```
set (db-lib-source
    dbmanager.h
    dbmanager.cpp
)

add_library(db-lib ${db-lib-source})

target_link_libraries(
    db-lib
    Qt5::Sql    
)
```

**src/db/dbmanager.h**:

```
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
...
```

**src/db/dbmanager.cpp**:

```
#include "dbmanager.h"

#include <QtSql/QSqlQuery>
...
```

**src/engine/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
set(engine-lib-source
    scanner.h
    scanner.cpp
)

add_library(engine-lib ${engine-lib-source})
```

**src/engine/scanner.h**:

```
#include <QtCore>
...
```

**src/engine/scanner.cpp**:

```
#include "scanner.h"
...
```

Comment: shouldn't it just be [`#include <QSqlDatabase>'](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html)?

Comment: no it doesn't solve the problem, but thanks for the comment!

Comment: Who downvoted this question could explain it to me, what did I wrong questioning this topic? Sorry for being a beginner in cmake, but I think I proposed my question briefly and I don't understand why you had to downvote this... I have been struggling with this problem for 2 days now... There are multiple other topics regarding cmake that are just 2 lines and upvoted... I don't blame you for downvoting me, just explain what did I do wrong  and how can I improve...

Comment: do you have the absolute path of this file?

Comment: yes I have it, it is in:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/qsqldatabase.h

Comment: using it does not solve the problem?

Comment: Is `QSqlDatabase` in that folder in addition to `qsqldatabase.h`?

Comment: I don't understand what is the `include(Qt)` for in your `CMakeLists.txt`. Do you need to add this include directory?

Comment: @ignacio that is the header file I am trying to pull, without include(Qt) it is:

  Target "blacklist-engine-cli" links to target "Qt5::Core" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?

Comment: @drescherjm yes

Comment: what happens if you move `REQUIRED` in `CMakeLists.txt` to the end of the statement like `find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Sql REQUIRED)`?

Comment: that didn't change anything unfortunatelly, in the meantime I think I made some progress, I modified src/db/CMakeLists.txt (see above) and the error message (see above) is different now

Comment: Maybe engine-lib did not successfully build.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was down-voted. It's a great, well-documented question, and indicates the issue was already researched.

Comment: @squareskittles I'm just going to point out that the third criteria for down-vote is if the person finds the question useful.  The usefulness of a question can be pretty subjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is because `engine-lib` is never built, and its CMake file is never even processed. The offending line in your CMake file is this one:

```
add_subdirectory(
    db   
    engine
)
```

When using [`add_subdirectory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/add_subdirectory.html) in this manner, the second argument becomes the **binary** directory for the generated content related to `db`. As a result, you may notice that CMake placed some build artifacts in your `src/engine` directory, which is probably not what you want.

To fix this, you must call `add_subdirectory` consecutive times for including multiple sub-directories.

```
add_subdirectory(db)
add_subdirectory(engine)
```